# Python - Json export to txt adds unexpected characters/separators

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to write a json object to a txt file to be used in an other program.
The file generated by code presents unexpected behavior (in my opinion):

```
f = {'nt' : 50, 'nt_array': [10,20,30] }
json_obj = json.dumps(f)
f=open('out.txt','w')
f.write(json.dumps(json_obj)
f.close()
```

This code produce a txt file with the following content:

```
"{\"nt_array\": [10, 20, 30], \"nt\": 50}"
```

But I want this:

```
{"nt_array": [10, 20, 30], "nt": 50}
```

It adds some separators / and ".

Comment: You made redundant calls to `json.dumps`.

Comment: … which means you're JSONifying the string made by JSONifying the object.

Comment: As a side note, is there a reason you're using `json.dumps` to build a string just to write to a file, instead of using `json.dump`?

Comment: @abarnert It is simplified version on my code to be more readable

Comment: @TommasoF: But using `dumps` instead of `dump` here makes your code longer and less readable, not simplified and more readable…

Comment: @abarnert yes `dump` is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You encoded to JSON **twice**:

```
>>> import json
>>> obj = {'nt' : 50, 'nt_array': [10,20,30] }
>>> print json.dumps(obj)
{"nt_array": [10, 20, 30], "nt": 50}
>>> print json.dumps(json.dumps(obj))
"{\"nt_array\": [10, 20, 30], \"nt\": 50}"
```

Just use the [`json.dump()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump) (no `s` at the end) *once* and write directly to the file:

```
obj = {'nt' : 50, 'nt_array': [10,20,30] }
with open('out.txt','w') as f:
    json.dump(obj, f)
```

Note the use of `with` to have the file closed automatically as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove one of the calls to `json.dumps`.  The first call gives you the value you want, the second call produces the escaped format that you don't want.